# Vue directive called but not updating value

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-directives

My `uppercase` directive below works fine with `<input>`:

```
<input
  type="text"
  v-model="foo"
  v-uppercase
>
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work with `<b-form-input>`:

```
<b-form-input
  type="text"
  v-model="foo"
  v-uppercase
></b-form-input>
```

The `uppercase` directive:

```
  directives: {
    uppercase: {
      update: function (el) {
        el.value = el.value.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there something wrong in my code ? How should I fix it ?

Comment: May I ask you why you don't use a computed property  ?

Comment: I would need to use many computed properties while a directive can be re-used.

Comment: you can use filter instead like `v-model="foo | uppercase"`

Comment: What is a `b-form-input`?

Comment: in the  first input, the uppercase directive change the last inserted character to uppercase but doesn't affect the last character in the foo variable in the data... is it not a problem ?

Comment: @LannyBose https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#comp-ref-b-form-input

Comment: @F_Mekk no, that's another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just change to uppercase easiest way is use style:

```
.uppercase{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Also use filter can another choice:

```
    filters: {
        uppercase: function(v) {
            return v.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

And if you want use directive as you use v-model got some problems so you can combine it with style solution:

```
Vue.directive("uppercase", {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
    },
    update(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
    }
});
```

Here is [simple codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/QWjmZVm) for directive for show all solutions